# How to install multiple instances of a service on a host with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a host on which I want to install the same service multiple times, but with different paths, service names, etc. (stuff that can be configured via variables).

I usually don't use the same host for this, but this is a special use-case scenario and I can't change the architecture.

What is the optimal way of doing this using Ansible (I am already using 2.0)?

Comment: Ansible is an automation framework. You define the tasks you would have run manually otherwise. If you know what you want to do, then you should know what you need to do with Ansible. Either you're asking the wrong question or your question is to broad. Either way, the answer would highly depend on the details of your application. How is the application installed (e.g. unzipping stuff vs. installing an rpm), do you need multiple copies of the application or one copy which gets started with different configuration...

Comment: The application is installed by unzipping an archive, and I need multiple copies of the application. Each copy of the application must be configured differently - unarchived in a different location, with different configuration files, etc. What I am trying to find out is if I can do that differently (with less redundancy) than just creating another role with a different name that I would apply to that host. For example, the way I see it now, I can make a role consisting of app-1 and another one for app-2, and apply both to that host's playbook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given you have a role to install your application, you could use roll parameters to configure all the moving pieces.

```
- role: cool-app
  location: /some/path/A
  config:
    some: stuff

- role: cool-app
  location: /some/path/B
  config:
    some: other stuff
```

Then inside your role you could directly access `{{ location }}` and `{{ config.some }}` etc.

---

A bit more dynamic but also more complex to create - especially if you already have this working role and now need to change it - is to loop all tasks over a set of instances.

You could again pass this as role parameters:

```
- role: cool-app
  instances:
    - location: /some/path/A
      config:
        some: stuff
    - location: /some/path/B
      config:
        some: other stuff
```

Or better define it in your host- or group-vars.

Then every task which is unique to an instance would need to loop over the `instances` variable. So for example unzipping:

```
- unarchive:
    src: cool-app.tgz
    dest: "{{ item.location }}"
  with_items: instances
```

Comment: Okay, I now understand how this works - my concern was that I could not use the same role, even with different variables, which might silly but it did cross my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [udondan's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34904713) there
is a third solution. Let's consider following directory structure:

```
host_vars/myapp01.yml
host_vars/myapp02.yml

roles/touch/tasks/main.yml

inventory.yml
play.yml
```

and following file contents:

```
# host_vars/myapp01.yml
myvar: myval01

# host_vars/myapp02.yml
myvar: myval02

# roles/touch/tasks/main.yml
- name: touch
  command: touch {{ myvar }}

# inventory.yml
myapp01 ansible_host=192.168.0.1
myapp02 ansible_host=192.168.0.1

# play.yml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - touch
```

**Idea**

The idea is to alias host with app instance names (one alias per instance of
application). In the example two aliases (*myapp01* and *myapp02*) target the same
host: *192.168.0.1*. Now this two instances of application are treated by
ansible exactly as two separate hosts and:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.ini
```

will install two instances of application (touch files *myval01* and *myval02*)
on host *192.168.0.1*.

**Advantages**

This solution allows, for example, to execute play only on one instance of
application:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.ini --limit myapp01
```

**Note**

Two DNS or IP addresses also can target the same machine.